# Access: query form.recordSource to go to a certain record in a subform, bound to a different table

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, controls

I have a form bound to TableA, and a subform contained in this form, bound to TableB.

TableA and TableB are related through a given field, and what I am trying to do with this whole thing is:

1. query TableA using input from mainform to find a single record in Me.RecordSource
2. query TableB using input from mainform to find a single record in [TableB], or put another way, query TableB to find the record related to the record found in (1.)
3. Move the subform to the record found in (2.)
4. Using a button in mainform, update Me.RecordSource with the information introduced in the subform/TableB

I have put my brain to work this out for hours but to nothing but a headache. I am kind of new to Access and VBA, but this is seriously driving me crazy. No VBA code nor macro I could manage to code helped me do this. Any tips?

Comment: You just need to set the MasterLinkField and ChildLinkField of the subform control on the main form.

Comment: That much I already had figured out, what I am really struggling with is the 'save' button. My approach is to create a querydef with an sql update statement and execute it, updating the values in TableA with the recordset of a query on TableB which points to the record (I use a second query on TableB because I can't manage to read the subform controls), but it doesn't work somehow :(  Thanks a lot for your comment and help by the way! :D

Comment: You can read the current field values of the subform from the controls on the subform.

Comment: Could you please add the code to do that? I have tried `FormName.Form!subformControlName.controlName.value` (and some variations of this) but it didn't work

Comment: It is `Me!subformControlName.Form!controlName.Value`.

Comment: You are a true savior @Gustav :D